# Integral of hypergeometric function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

Good morning,
I need help with the following integral
$$ \int_0 ^1  \left(\log (y) \frac{y^{a -1}  {}_2F_1(a ,a ;2 a ;y)}{y-x} - \log (x) \frac{x^2 y^{a -3} {}_2F_1(a ,a ;2 a;y)}{y-x}\right) dy$$
where ${}_2F_1(a ,a ;2 a ;y)$ is the Gauss hypergeometric function, $a>0$ and $0<x<1$. I am looking for a result in terms of multivariate hypergeometric functions (Horn, Kampè de Feriet, Lauricella etc), if a simpler results does not exist. I tried expanding in series or using an integral representation for the hypergeometric function.
Can anyone help me?